# How to get value at X Position on a dropdown field?

Tags: javascript, drop-down-menu

If i have a dropdown list that looks like this:

```
<select id="select">
<option value="Armoire">Armoire</option>
<option value="Bridge Bed">Brigde Bed</option>
<option value="Bunk Bed">Bunk Bed</option>
</select>
```

Is it possible to get the value at an specific position? For example:

```
var b=select.getValueAt(1);
```

so that b would equal to "Bridge Bed". That would be the right line for regular java code. Is there anyway to do this using javascript?

Thanks in advance,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The select element has an property called options which is an array of all the option tags it contains
To get the value of element at index one use

```
var b = document.getElementById('select').options[1].value
```

[Select Object](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-2-HTML/html.html#ID-94282980)
[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mowglisanu/r2WwK/)

Comment: Thank you a lot for the quick response. That was very helpful. I works  perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you've already manage to get the `<select>` element somehow:

```
var idx = 1;
var selectTag = document.getElementById('select');
var b = selectTag.getElementsByTagName("option")[idx].getAttribute("value");
```

This uses proper DOM methods to do the work and will get all child `<option>` tags, including those in `<optgroup>`. The index ignores `<optgroup>` and indexes all `<option>` tags from 0. An example (which `alert`s the value) is [here](http://ibboard.co.uk/temp/option-index.html)